# What does 3D gaze direction contains? And how to convert to yaw and pitch?

Tags: 3d, camera, geometry, camera-calibration

I am trying to use a dataset. But I am facing two problems or confusions in understanding it.

1. Can anbody guide me what 3D gaze direction stands for or what does it mean (angles, (x, y, z) coordinates or what)?

Suppose i have normalized data containing eye images along with 3D gaze head pose and 3D gaze direction. It is being normalized in camera space. The values for 3D gaze direction are like (-0.1173, 0.2479, -0.9616).

- if this 3D gaze Direction are angles than what are they and what should I call them?

  2. I want to convert this 3D gaze direction to Yaw and Pitch. Can anybody guide me how I can convert it?

     - If they are angles than how can I convert them?
     - if they are (x, y, z) coordinates, than, is below equations correct to calculate yaw and pitch angles:

       yaw    = θ =  arctan(y/x)

       pitch  = ϕ =  arctan((√(x^2+y^2))/z)

Answer (score 0):

They are not angles. They are the x, y, z coordinates of a point situated on the unit sphere. The gaze direction is the ray starting at the center of the sphere and passing through this point. Note how the norm of this vector is 1. ("normalized in camera space").

To convert to orientation angles you need to know how the coordinate system is defined (e.g: is z looking forward or upward?), then you can use your spherical coordinates conversions.